# Open txt file in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I want to open a txt file (need to pop open file dialog box and the same folder as the current template)

Then this file need to read as xlsx rather than txt.

This is my current code setup:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim intChoice As Integer

'Select the start folder
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
    ).InitialFileName = "I:\Group -*******Chages here******"
'make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
'determine what choice the user made
If intChoice <> 0 Then

***** CODE HERE********

End If
End Sub
```

Can someone identify my mistakes?

Comment: And what exactly is a problem with your code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code snippet (it works) and modify it pertinent to your development task:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog

   ' set up the File Dialog var
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fDialog

      'sample init file name
      .InitialFileName = "C:\Text.txt"

       ' set the title of the Dialog box
      .Title = "Please select the file to open"

      ' Clear the current and add some sample filters
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt"
      .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      'Show dialog box: if .Show method returns True then execute the code
      If .Show = True Then
          'Add code here
      Else
         MsgBox "File Open operation Canceled."
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Hope this may help. Kind regards,

Comment: Thx a lot. This goes and let me open the file I wat. But I want to read that file and keep as xls rather than txt. can anyone help me further?

Comment: I am glad it works for you. If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it and post your second question separately. We will try to help you on that other issue either. Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this:

```
Dim fname
fname = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt", , , , True)
If IsArray(fname) Then Workbooks.OpenText fname(1)
```

To see the available arguments *OpenText Method* offers, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097(v=office.15).aspx). HTH.